# Implementing a filter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have implemented a filter for filtering a `IEnumerable` of a specific type.

To accomblish this goal i have created three classes: `FilterOption`, `Filter` and the `FilterManager`.

**FilterOption.cs**

```
public class FilterOption<TFilterOptionType>
{
    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            this.OnIsSelectedChanged(new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public TFilterOptionType Option { get; private set; }

    public FilterOption(TFilterOptionType option)
    {
        this.Option = option;
    }

    public event EventHandler IsSelectedChanged;

    protected virtual void OnIsSelectedChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        IsSelectedChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

**Filter.cs**

```
public class Filter<TFilterType, TFilterOptionType>
{
    public bool IsActive => this.Options.Any(option => option.IsSelected);

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<TFilterType> FilteredItems{ get; }

    public List<FilterOption<TFilterOptionType>> Options { get; set; }

    private Func<TFilterType, TFilterOptionType> PropertyGetter { get; }

    public Filter(
        string name,
        IEnumerable<TFilterType> items,
        ObservableCollection<TFilterType> filteredItems,
        Func<TFilterType, TFilterOptionType> propertyGetter)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.FilteredItems = filteredItems;
        this.PropertyGetter = propertyGetter;
        this.Options =
            items.Select(x => this.PropertyGetter(x))
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(option => option)
                .Select(option => new FilterOption<TFilterOptionType>(option))
                .ToList();
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        if (this.IsActive)
        {
            foreach (var option in this.Options.Where(option => !option.IsSelected))
            {
                this.FilteredItems.RemoveAll(item => this.PropertyGetter(item).Equals(option.Option));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FilterManager.cs**

```
public class FilterManager<TFilterType>
{
    public ObservableCollection<Filter<TFilterType, IComparable>> Filters { get; set; } =
        new ObservableCollection<Filter<TFilterType, IComparable>>();

    public ObservableCollection<TFilterType> FilteredItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TFilterType>();

    private IEnumerable<TFilterType> Items { get; }

    public FilterManager(IEnumerable<TFilterType> items)
    {
        this.Items = items;
        this.FilteredItems.Add(this.Items);
    }

    public void AddFilter(string filterName, Func<TFilterType, IComparable> propertyGetter)
    {
        var filter = new Filter<TFilterType, IComparable>(filterName, this.Items, this.FilteredItems, propertyGetter);
        this.Filters.Add(filter);

        foreach (var filterOption in filter.Options)
        {
            filterOption.IsSelectedChanged += this.OptionDisabled;
        }
    }

    private void OptionDisabled(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.FilteredItems.Clear();
        this.FilteredItems.Add(this.Items);
        foreach (var filter in this.Filters)
        {
            filter.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

---

The implemented `FilterManager` provides the option to add any filter. You can do this with calling

```
YourFilterManagerInstance.AddFilter("Name of the Filter", item => item.ItemProperty);
```

---

One FilterManager can be shown in WPF with this XAML (and the right Setting to a proper ViewModel)

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding BindingToFilterManager.Filters}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Separator />
                <Expander Width="300">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource ToUpperCaseConverter}}"
                                   FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Option}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                          Margin="0, 3, 3, 3" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: i am not really happy with the event, maybe you have a better solution in mind

Comment: You have a typo in the property name "FilterdItems".

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you can't use the standard WPF filtering? At first glance your code looks extremely complex and bug-prone. I think you should keep it simple and use the existing abstractions instead. In your case I would go for something like:

```
interface IFilter<T>
{
    bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    event Action IsEnabledChanged; 

    bool Filter(T item);
}
```

Then I would use standard `CollectionViewSource` filtering:

```
//Bind this collection of filters to the filter list in your UI
Filters = new IFilter<T>[] { .... };
//load or create the collection of actual items you want to filter
var items = new ObserbaleCollection<T>();
//Bind this collection view to the item list in your UI
Items = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(items);
//Set up the filter
//This will only show an item if it passes every enabled filter. 
//You might want to tweak this logic if you need different behaviour
Items.Filter = item => Filters.Where(f => f.IsEnabled).All(f => f.Filter((T)item));
```

What's left is to wire `IsEnabledChanged` event to `Items.Refresh()` method and you should be good to go.

Comment: i will take a look on this